# What is the meaning of 看在 and 分上?

Tags: grammar, meaning, vocabulary

> 看在孩子的分上，夫妇二人没有离婚。

In the phrase above, what do they mean?
Neither is found in a dictionary.

The sentence is said to translate to "The pair would not divorce because of the children".

Comment: 看在 = for the sake of. 分 = separate. 上 is here just a complement.

Comment: I think the `分` should be [份](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/xs/4EFD.htm). `(4) 情分;情面 [affection]。如:看在妈的份上,别理他`

Comment: @songyuanyao Agreed, and I think that's the key to understanding this structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

看在

**ABC**

> 2 be for the sake of ...
>
> 看在你爸的面子上, 我原谅你。
>
> Kànzài nǐ bà de miànzi shàng, wǒ yuánliàng nǐ.
>
> For the sake of your father's face, I forgive you.

份上

**Guifan**

> 2 名 情分; 情面
>
> 看在老人的份上, 我不再跟他计较。
>
> (口语中也说份儿上。)

Which basically translates to *feelings, sensibilities, affections*.

for the sake of, for sb.'s/sth.'s sake

**ABC ENGLISH**

> wèile ( ... de lìyì) 为了(…的利益) ; kànzài ... de fèn shang 看在…的份上
>
> We must do this for the sake of the children.
>
> 为了孩子,我们必须做这件事。
>
> Wèile háizi, wǒmen bìxū zuò zhè jiàn shì.

So now we have our 看在…的份上 construct meaning roughly the equivalent of "for the sake of, for sb.'s/sth.'s sake" where 看在 means "for the sake" and "份上" means feelings or sensibilities.

You can stick anything in the middle for the "who's" sake/sensibilities/feelings/etc.

Some examples: (from Oxford)

> for God's sake
>
> 看在上帝的分上

> for Pete's sake!
>
> 看在老天的份上！

> for heaven's sake
>
> 看在上帝的份上

Answer (score 2):

I would parse this as 看, look, 在, at, preposition (or result complement), 孩子, kids, 的, possessive particles, 分, separation, 上, a postposition forming a "prepositional sandwich" with 在. So literally, I would translate it to "Looking on the side of the children", which I would then render more loosely as "for the children's sake". So neither of those should be single words, they should both be two words, `kàn zài` and `fèn shàng`.

Then again, this is just my two cents, and I'm neither an expert, nor someone who's ever seen these two character combinations before, nor a mother-tongue.

Comment: I did not read your answer at first. I think you have analyzed it correctly

Answer (score 0):

People I ask agree with user3306356 it's '看在 。。。的份上' which means 'because of'.

A bit more info I got: There is a saying 《不看僧面看佛面》 《不看僧》 means 《不看在僧的份上》and 《看佛面》means 《看在佛的份上》

Not for the sake of the monk, but for the sake of the Buddha.